# Error instalacion nodejs ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nodejs, angular, ubuntu

Estoy intentando instar **nodejs** en mi sist operativo **Ubuntu 16.04**, ejecute los siguientes comandos:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Y me genera el siguiente error en la consola:

```
W: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar y por        tanto su uso es potencialmente peligroso.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
W: Error de GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease: Las firmas siguientes no se pudieron verificar porque su clave pública no está disponible: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
W: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease» no está firmado.
N: Los datos de un repositorio como este no se pueden autenticar y por tanto su uso es potencialmente peligroso.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido,  o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Si me pueden orientar, porque soy nuevo en Ubuntu y me esta costando. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolverlo haciendo lo siguiente:
En *Configuraciòn del sistema  > Software y actualizaciones*, destilde las opciones que muestro en los rectangulos rojos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en la consola ejecute

`sudo apt update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

y se soluciono el problema.